# How to extend a recursive typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a recursive interface like the following:

```
interface TreeNode {
  id: string
  children: TreeNode[]
}
```

and I want to extend `TreeNode` like this:

```
interface TreeNodeWithMorePros extends TreeNode{
  moreProps: any[]
}
```

but this is not enough since the `root` can have `moreProps` but the children can't.

```
const tree: TreeNodeWithMorePros = {
  id: 'root', 
  moreProps: [], 
  children: [
    {
      id: 'child', 
      children: [],
      // here I cannot use moreProps
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I properly extend the `TreeNode` interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found the solution

There is a polymorphic type `this` which can be used:

```
interface TreeNode {
  id: string
  children: this[]
}

interface TreeNodeWithMorePros extends TreeNode{
  moreProps: any[]
}

const tree: TreeNodeWithMorePros = {
  id: 'something',
  moreProps: [],
  children: [
    {
      id: 'child',
      children: [],
      moreProps: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Now it works fine